# Running a python program from jupyter notebook while passing filenames as arguments

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to run a program named "Volatility_Spreadsheet_Prepare.py" from jupyter notebook while passing multiple files as arguments to the program. My code is as follows:

```
for filename in all_csv_files:
    %run 'Volatility_Spreadsheet_Prepare.py' filename
```

Here, `all_csv_files` contains a list of all the CSV files in the current directory. This program takes filename as an argument.

Here, jupyter notebook considers filename as a string while I want it to consider the name stored in the variable 'filename' of the for loop. How do I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Jupyter Notebook expands variables with $name, bash-style.

Try something like this (note the '$' infront of filename):

```
for filename in all_csv_files:
    %run 'Volatility_Spreadsheet_Prepare.py' $filename
```

See [here](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#line-magics) for more information

Comment: you may also have to modify your filenames if they contain spaces: ' ' -> '\ '

Comment: @wotter Regarding this. If I am fetching a list of all files in the directory and one or more of the file names contains spaces, how do I pass these filenames as arguments without having to do it manually. For example:- If am using the following code: `%run $script 'CMVOLT_01102018 (1).CSV'`, it runs as expected but when I am storing the file name 'CMVOLT_01102018 (1).CSV' in a variable `filename` and then running the same command: `%run $script $filename`, it gives me a FileNotFoundError: `File b'CMVOLT_01102018' does not exist` How do I deal with this?

Comment: try to replace the space in the filename variable by '\ ': something like `filename=filename.replace(' ', '\ ')` ?

Answer (score 1):

Type this

```
!python Volatility_Spreadsheet_Prepare.py all_csv_files
```

Comment: It gives an error: No module named pandas. I have pandas installed. What is the problem here?

Comment: Open an interactive python shell, type `import pandas`. From the error, you may be able to tell the problem. Alternatively install pandas using pip or conda.